# How to make sort function to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have array of objects. Each object contains name and user_id property.

```
const queue = [
  {
    user: 1,
    song: "Song1",
  },
  {
    user: 1,
    song: "Song2",
  },
  {
    user: 2,
    song: "Song3",
  },
  {
    user: 1,
    song: "Song4",
  },
  {
    user: 3,
    song: "Song5",
  },
];
```

I would like to sort it so it will look like this

```
const queue = [
  {
    user: 1,
    song: "Song1",
  },
  {
    user: 2,
    song: "Song3",
  },
  {
    user: 3,
    song: "Song5",
  },
  {
    user: 1,
    song: "Song2",
  },

  {
    user: 1,
    song: "Song4",
  },

];
```

So. If user 1 adds 10 songs to queue, user 2 adds 1 song to queue and user 3 adds 3 songs to queue, queue will look like `user_1_entry,user_2_entry,user_3_entry,user_1_entry,user_3_entry,user_1_entry, user_3_entry, user_1_entry [...]`

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What is the logic for the sorting? Just repeat 1-3 until exhausted?

Comment: @VLAZ I am trying to make "friendly queue" system. So if new user adds something to queue, he don't have to wait until all previous songs will be played.

Comment: I'd personally just keep a queue for each user and then do a round-robin through them when picking the next song. Seems a lot easier to debug and maintain instead of re-shuffling the same list all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) by using a temporary object with a hashtable for the same group array. Take the length of the used array as group for sorting.

The sorting happens with the group and index.

The result is mapped with index of the sorted temporary array.

```js
const
    queue = [{ user: 1, song: "Song1" }, { user: 1, song: "Song2" }, { user: 2, song: "Song3" }, { user: 1, song: "Song4" }, { user: 3, song: "Song5" }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = queue
        .map(({ user }, index) => ({ index, group: groups[user] = (groups[user] || 0) + 1 }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group || a.index - b.index)
        .map(({ index }) => queue[index]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fast and less iteration`. Group element based on user and collect song one by one from all user

```js
    const queue = [
      { user: 1, song: "Song1" },
      { user: 1, song: "Song2" },
      { user: 2, song: "Song3" },
      { user: 1, song: "Song4" },
      { user: 3, song: "Song5" },
    ];
    const mapper = (data) => {
      return data.reduce((m, i) => {
        if (!m[i.user]) m[i.user] = [];
        m[i.user].push(i);
        return m;
      }, []);
    };
    const collect = (queue) => {
      const mappedData = mapper(queue);
      let result = [],
        counter = 0,
        row = 0;
      while (counter < queue.length) {
        if (mappedData[row] && mappedData[row].length) {
          const d = mappedData[row].shift();
          result.push(d);
          counter++;
        }
        row++;
        if (row === mappedData.length) row = 0;
      }
      return result;
    };
    console.log(collect(queue));
    // chunkSort(queue);
```